# Php code: Adding items to a cart using a form with radio buttons

Tags: php, cart

I'm trying to create a cart system for an old project using PHP. I tend to make small mistakes, so please forgive me. My form is as follows:

```
<form action="connect.php" method="POST">
<p>Size:
  <input type="radio" name="size" value="small"> Small
  <input type="radio" name="size" value="medium"> Medium
  <input type="radio" name="size" value="large"> Large
  <input type="radio" name="size" value="x-large"> X-large
  <input type="radio" name="size" value="xx-large"> XX-large
  </p></form><br>

<p>Color:
<input type="radio" name="color" value="black"> Black
<input type="radio" name="color" value="blue"> Blue
<input type="radio" name="color" value="red"> Red
<input type="radio" name="color" value="white"> White
</p></form><br>

  <p>Quantity:
    <select name="quantity">
    <option value="1" name="amt">1</option>
    <option value="2" name="amt">2</option>
    <option value="3" name="amt">3</option>
    <option value="4" name="amt">4</option>
    <option value="5" name="amt">5</option>
    </select>
  </p>
  <br>
  <input id="addItem" class="btn" type="submit" name="addItem" value="Add to Cart">
</form>
```

The PHP is below. I'm having difficulty with making the form submit and check that my database has the items. Once I can get that to work, I want the code to retrieve that information and actually add it to the "cart" for purchase.

```
<?php
 session_start();
include_once("connect.php");

if (isset($_POST['addItem'])) {
// echo "working";
$search_size = $_GET['size'];
$search_color = $_GET['color'];
//$search_amt = $_GET['amt'];

$addingSize = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * FROM 'products' WHERE 'prod_name' like '%$search_size%'");
$addingColor = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * FROM 'products' WHERE 'prod_color' like '%$search_color%'");
//$addingAmt = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * FROM 'products' WHERE 'prod_name' like '%$search_size%'");

//fetch info and put into cart

//mysqli_fetch_array(result,resulttype);
while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($conn,MYSQLI_BOTH)){
$price = $row['price'];
$name = $row['prod_name'];
$size = $row['prod_size'];
$color = $row['prod_color'];

echo "<h1>added to cart</h1>";
 }
}

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your call to mysql_fetch_array is incorrect.

```
$addingSize = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * FROM 'products' WHERE 'prod_name' like '%$search_size%'");
$addingColor = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * FROM 'products' WHERE 'prod_color' like '%$search_color%'");

//fetch info and put into cart
while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($conn,MYSQLI_BOTH)){
    ...
}
```

The first parameter to mysqli_fetch_array should be the mysqli_result resource, not the connection resource.

Try changing it to

```
while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($addingSize,MYSQLI_BOTH))
```

And you should be able to iterate over the results of that first query.

Then fetch the results from the second query with

```
while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($addingColor,MYSQLI_BOTH))
```

Comment: Thank you very much! When I change the while() loops, should I add the same information after? while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($addingColor,MYSQLI_BOTH)) { ... }

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, remove the quotes for your table and column selections from both
`FROM 'products' WHERE 'prod_name'` and `FROM 'products' WHERE 'prod_color'`.

Those are being passed as string literals.

- Either use ticks or remove them.

Ticks example:

```
SELECT * FROM `products` WHERE `prod_name`
```

- Consult: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/identifier-qualifiers.html

about identifier qualifiers.

Having used error checking on your queries, would have triggered syntax errors.

- http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php

Add `or die(mysqli_error($conn))` to `mysqli_query()` and you will see for yourself.

---

Then you're using the wrong variable `$conn` in:

```
while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($conn,MYSQLI_BOTH))
                              ^^^^^ // incorrect variable, syntax error.
```

Use either `$addingSize` or `$addingColor` depending on which one is to fetch the query you want. You also may want to use two different `while`'s but unsure as to which query you wish to echo in your loop and from which query it's for; only you know which one.

Then these GET arrays:

```
$search_size = $_GET['size'];
$search_color = $_GET['color'];
//$search_amt = $_GET['amt'];
```

- Those should be POST and not GET, as per your form method being "post".

Another thing, in your dropdown select:

```
<select name="quantity">
<option value="1" name="amt">1</option>
<option value="2" name="amt">2</option>
<option value="3" name="amt">3</option>
<option value="4" name="amt">4</option>
<option value="5" name="amt">5</option>
</select>
```

Only `<select>` bears the "name" attribute, not `<option>`. Therefore `<select name="quantity">` should bear the "amt" name attribute and not "quantity".

---

Add [**error reporting**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php) to the top of your file(s) which will help find errors.

```
<?php 
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

// rest of your code
```

**Sidenote:** Error reporting should only be done in staging, and never production.

Comment: Thank you Fred!! I used both your suggestions and the other user's to alter my code and will see what comes of it.

Comment: @JadeAmerica you're welcome. Btw, I've made a few edits in the past 10 mins, and unsure if you've seen them. Reload my answer again just in case, there were additional syntax issues.

Comment: Thank you, I changed the sql query to `$addingSize = mysqli_query($conn,SELECT * FROM products WHERE prod_name like %$search_size%);` and keep getting errors from it? Don't mean to be a n00b...

Comment: **Parse error:** syntax error, unexpected 'products' (T_STRING) in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/xlii_2/item_code/baseball.php on line 95

Comment: @JadeAmerica you have `like '%$search_size%'` in quotes in your question but in comments here, you wrote `like %$search_size%` without them.

Comment: after you mentioned to take the quotations away, I took them all away. Should I take the `like %$search_size%` out in general?

Comment: @JadeAmerica sure, if you want to. Once you've gotten one to work, you can then add on later.